# Jquery fade in not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change an img src then set opacity to 0 then fade in.

```
 $("#featureImg").attr('src','07.jpg').css({opacity:0}).fadeIn("slow");
```

This works up to the

```
.css({opacity:0})
```

Meaning it does set the opacity to 0,but the fade never happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is caused by using CSS opacity of zero in combination with fadeIn(). To hide the element and then fadeIn(), you should use .css({display: 'none'}) or .hide() followed by fadeIn(), like so:

```
   $("#featureImg").attr('src','07.jpg').css({display:'none'}).fadeIn("slow");
```

or

```
   $("#featureImg").attr('src','07.jpg').hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

The purpose of fadeIn() is to show a "hidden" element, "hidden" interpreted by jQuery to mean not displayed, and not with zero opacity.

Comment: @shelhameer , in that case you can use .hide().fadIn()

Comment: @kobe, I included .hide() in the text of my answer, but did not put it in the code examples. I have added it, since you mentioned it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An opacity value of 0 makes the object completely transparent. So when the fadeIn() works, it's fading in a transparent object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fade opacity then use `.fadeTo("slow", 1);` instead. Hiding the element will reflow the page and move content around so use this if you want everything to remain in position.